# Obtaining the title or header information and url of a webpage in android

Tags: android, url

I'm new to android app development and I've for sometime now been trying to find out how to get the title or header information as well as the url of a webpage into the app I'm developing. What I want to do is to take a site, say mashable.com for instance, and get the titles and urls of all the recent articles and display them in a simple list form in my app.
Any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> The application will take an RSS feed from the popular Android
>   developer site Androidster and parse it into a list of simple Java
>   objects that you can use to back an Android ListView (see Downloads
>   for the source code). This is classic polymorphic behavior — different
>   implementations (different XML parsing algorithms) that provide the
>   same behavior. Listing 1 shows how easily you can model this in Java
>   code using an interface.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/index.html

Taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253788/simple-rss-parser-for-android

Comment: Wow! Checked it out. Hell of an article. I'm not really good in java so its not really easy to understand everything. But I'm gonna sit down and make sure I do! Thanks.

Comment: No problem. I think it's what you're looking for though: you can't just read the HTML from a webpage to do what you're looking for. You can, however, get that info from the website via XML, RSS, or JSON. Reddit has a really good example of all this: https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki